# Inserting data into access using c#,net

Tags: c#, ms-access

Below is attached code, Code is working fine, But it is not inserting the Values into access database tables that I have created, Neither Code shows any error

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            }

            private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)                
            {      
                OleDbConnection cnon = new OleDbConnection();
                cnon.ConnectionString =@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\visual_c\Database71.accdb";
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO electricity (Asset_name,Asset_number)VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
                cnon.Open();
                command.Connection = cnon;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cnon.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the event hanlder of the submit button is attached to submit_Click?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space in here:

```
"(Asset_name,Asset_number)VALUES"
```

try to change your command string:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO electricity (Asset_name,Asset_number) VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
```

And you should use [parameterized queries](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) to prevent [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO electricity (Asset_name,Asset_number) VALUES(@name,@number)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", textBox2.Text);
```

Comment: I tried using command parameteres but still not working. It is still not showing any error, nor it is inserting any values in access after i click submit

Answer (score 0):

Use parameteraized query
Make sure your button  OnClick event

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO electricity (Asset_name,Asset_number) VALUES (@Assetname,@Assetnumber)",cnon;

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assetname", textBox1.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assetnumber", textBox2.Text);
```

Comment: I Tried again with parameters and in new windows form application and it worked..thanks lot